# Select all files between "thresholds"

Tags: bash, shell

In my directory I have a list of files like this (sorted):

```
A.txt
B.txt
...
Z.txt
```

In the variables `min_threshold` and `max_threshold` I have filenames, which represents the range of files that I want to copy (eg. between C.txt and K.txt). I am asking if there is a way to select a range of sorted files (using filename), and without using `while read`.

I am using this option:

```
files_names=$(ls $dir | sort | cut -d 'C.txt' -f 2)
files_names=$(echo $files_names | sort | cut -d 'K.txt' -f 1)
```

But cut only works with characters. Maybe I should use find and replace the filenames with a character.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: @ghoti thanks for the feedback

Comment: @JoãoCardoso: Why the line `without using while read`, so you already tried with it and not want it?

Comment: @Inian I think the solution is far from elegant and I want to learn more "bash hacks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ls` lists the files in a sorted order, it isn't clear that you need the `sort` after it.  However, assuming that the names are 'normal' (no spaces, newlines, tabs in the names), then:

```
file1="C.txt"
file2="K.txt"
filenames=$(ls | sort | sed -n "/$file1/,/$file2/p")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with eval, but must be sure about what you will execute since eval can execute malicious code:

```
$ ls *.txt
c.txt  d.txt  e.txt  f.txt
$ min="c.txt";max="e.txt"
$ ext="${min#*.}"     #Get the extension
$ minn="${min%.*}";maxn="${max%.*}"   #get everything before the extension (c and e)
$ eval ls "{$minn..$maxn}"."$ext"   # executed as ls {c..e}.txt
c.txt  d.txt  e.txt
```